# Ruby access hash value by a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's consider this as our hash `c = {:test => {:foo => true}}`

Normally, if we would like to print value of foo, we would access the hash like this `c[:test][:foo]` but I would like to access it dynamically based on my variable.

Therefore, let's consider the following variable `path = [[:test],[:foo]]`.

How do I access the value true now? I have tried `c[path]` but it just says `nil`. What am I missing?

Comment: Why is your `path` variable a nested array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old good recursive Ruby 1.9+ solution:

```
hash = {:test => {:foo => true}}
path = [[:test],[:foo]]

path.flatten.reduce(hash) { |h, p| h[p] }
#⇒ true
```

Or, as @Stefan suggested in comments:

```
path.reduce(hash) { |h, (p)| h[p] }
# or even
path.reduce(hash) { |h, p| h[p.first] }
```

More defensive:

```
path.flatten.reduce(hash) { |h, p| h.nil? ? nil : h[p] }
```

Comment: You can avoid `flatten` via `path.reduce(hash) { |h, (p)| h[p] }`

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `dig`. You can check the doc of dig here [**`Hash#dig`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig)

```
c = { :test => { :foo => true } }
c[:test][:foo]
#=> true

c.dig(:test, :foo)
#=> true

path = [:test, :foo]
c.dig(*path)
#=> true
```

You just need to pass the hierarchy

> Note: The `*` before `path` in `c.dig(*path)` is reffered as **splat operator**

Comment: Their `path` is `[[:test],[:foo]]`, not `[:test, :foo]`.

Comment: It's a variable which can be changed.

Comment: Any way we just need to add `flatten` if the input value is `[[:test],[:foo]]`